# Spinner layout cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to customize the default appearance of a `Spinner` item.

I have defined a layout in a file by the name of :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

And here when initializing the spinner I am trying to assign this layout to it:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> nearByLocationsAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.spinner_item_layout,nearByLocationsArray);
```

- But it keeps saying that `spinner_item_layout cannot be resolved or
  is not a field` however it is present in the layout folder?
- Another related question is it possible to view and edit the default spinner layout
  xml file i.e. `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`

Comment: Why didn't you name it just `@+id/text1`?

Comment: don't use android.R but use R file from you project.

Comment: it is not in android.R.layout package but it is in R.layout package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
android.R.layout.spinner_item_layout
```

You are using the default layout. You have to supply the one you created instead. Depending on the how you named your layout that would be something like this:

```
R.layout.my_spinner_item
```